# RTMP: check if stream is online with Python

Tags: python, flash, rtmp

I have several Flash streams and I want to display only active/live/online streams. Can someone provide sample code that can check status of stream? or point out where I can grab it (I think Red5 and RTMPy should have this, but I completely don't have any experience with RTMP; there is also RTMP specification, but wiki says it is incomplete)? My target language is Python, but code in any language will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In case of connection lost or connection fail the code below will print error message.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from rtmpy.client import ClientFactory

reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 1935, ClientFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: @lex, as I understand this code just checks if there is a RTMP server on port 1935. But I want to check if particular stream (for example rtmp://fms.rambler.ru/live/sc2tv1 ) is online. Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly script prints when you run it with rtmp://fms.rambler.ru/live/sc2tv1?

Comment: @lex, is there any working package of rtmpy? Currently I have AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BaseProtocol' importing BaseProtocol from rtmpy.protocol.

Comment: Same error. Traceback is strange. It seems rtmpy changes python path or something else. Script trying to import foreign package from my system. Need to investigate...

Comment: BTW, did you install rtmpy like an Egg package or source?

Comment: @lex, I used virtualenv and pip install rtmpy. It looks like rtmpy issue, I created ticket at the trac: http://dev.rtmpy.org/ticket/82

Comment: Have you seen latest Development Source Code from GIT?